# lighty-enable-mod: command not found

Tags: camera

I'm just starting out with Raspberry Pi. Following the instructions to set up a security camera ([Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762494/Raspberry-Pi-HD-Surveillance-Camera-with-Motion-Ni)) all goes well until the command: `sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php` and I get the message: `sudo: lighty-enable-mod: command not found`. Despite searching far and wide I can't get any clues to what is going on. Help!?

---

```
Output from "sudo apt-get -y install lighttpd":
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
    libfam0 libterm-readkey-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl spawn-fcgi
Suggested packages:
    fam rrdtool apache2-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    libfam0 libterm-readkey-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl lighttpd spawn-fcgi
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 338 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,006 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
    libfam0 libterm-readkey-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl lighttpd spawn-fcgi
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

---

Comment: Are you sure you installed lighttpd package without errors? Can you paste output of: `sudo apt-get -y install lighttpd` ?

Comment: Good question Huczu. I've posted the output above. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error with -y parameter Simple use:

```
sudo apt-get install lighttpd
```

and accept when he ask to install or try to use

```
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install lighttpd
```

Comment: Thank you. It ran without error. I then saw that I had a similar E: message in the next command (sudo apt-get -y install php5-common php5-cgi php5) so tried that without the -y. I got a five E: messages (one was "E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.6.17+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]") and a final one: "E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-mis". I clearly need to understand the basics of all this better. Is there a reference that you can suggest? Thanks again.

Comment: This turned out to be a beginner's error of not updating - which solved the problem.